# Pregunta sobre prompt() en Js

Tags: javascript

Como podria hacer:

```js
 var name = prompt("Ingresa tu nombre");
document.write("Bienvenido " + name );
var question = prompt("¿Te animas a jugar?");
```

Primero que se ejecute prompt , despues que se muestre el mensaje de bienvenida en el document y nuevamente que se ejecute prompt.

Comment: De hecho ya lo está haciendo. Primero salta el primer prompt, cuando le das a aceptar se está escribiendo el nombre y luego salta el último prompt. ¿Qué es lo que no está haciendo como esperas?

Comment: El mensaje de bienvenida se imprime cuando se responde la segunda pregunta , quisiera que se imprima después de solo responder  la primera pregunta.

Comment: mmm, no, se imprime después del primer prompt. Mira: https://photos.app.goo.gl/ZmGL3lx8r5i380hh1

Comment: A mi también me pasa como a @user889 . Me salta el primer prompt, me salta el segundo prompt y después ya se escribe el mensaje en pantalla.

Comment: @M. Giner , otra consulta como podria guardar la respuesta del segundo prompt, gracias.

Comment: Edito mi respuesta, pero ya estás guardando la respuesta del segundo prompt en la variable "question"

Comment: @M. Giner , si basado la respuesta deseo que aparesca diferentes impresiones ¿cree que estaria bien usar un switch? , gracias.

Comment: Sii, sería lo ideal. Debajo de `document.write("El usuario "+name+" " + question + " se anima a jugar.");` es donde puedes poner el switch con las condiciones. Se agradeceria que marcaras mi respuesta como buena en caso de que lo hubiera sido :) Saludos!

Comment: ¿Estáis probando con Chrome? Parece que no se gestiona igual en Chrome que en IE y Firefox https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42449152/why-html-page-render-document-write-after-prompt-at-end-of-javascript?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes probar a poner un delay (un retardo) entre el mensaje de bienvenida y el segundo prompt, de por ejemplo 1 segundo o lo que desees.

Prueba esto:

```
var name = prompt("Ingresa tu nombre");
document.write("Bienvenido " + name );
setTimeout(function(){ var question = prompt("¿Te animas a jugar?"); }, 1000);
```

Después de escribir el mensaje en la pantalla, esperará 1 segundo y saltará el otro prompt.

**GUARDAR RESPUESTA DEL SEGUNDO PROMPT**

```
var name = prompt("Ingresa tu nombre");
document.write("Bienvenido " + name + "<br/>");
setTimeout(function(){
    var question = prompt("¿Te animas a jugar?");
    document.write("El usuario "+name+" " + question + " se anima a jugar.");

}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías optar por una opción que te resuelve dos problemas en uno:

- Te valida que no se escriban datos vacíos en el `prompt`. Esta validación podría ser extensiva, por medio de alguna función, por ejemplo, controlar valores sólo numéricos o con una determinada extensión, etc.
- Te escribe la información en el orden, porque la escribe después de haber validado.

Veamos un ejemplo en el que sólo validamos que el prompt no esté vacío:

```js
var strName=prompt( "Escribe tu nombre","" );
while (!strName) {
   strName=prompt( "Escribe tu nombre","" );
}

document.write( "Bienvenido " + strName + "<br />");

var strQuestion = prompt( strName + " ¿Te animas a jugar?", "" );
while (!strQuestion) {
   strQuestion = prompt( strName + "¿Te animas a jugar?", "" );
}

document.write( strName + ", tu respuesta ha sido: "+ strQuestion );
```